# Rspec: Tempfile subclass of File get intercepted by File stub request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, stub

I'm doing a stub request to `File` but since I call `Tempfile` (that is a subclass of `File`) before calling `File`, `Tempfile` is intercepting the stub I define.

**Model**:

```
def download_file
  #...
  begin
    tempfile = Tempfile.new([upload_file_name, '.csv'])
    File.open(tempfile, 'wb') { |f| f.write(result.body.to_s) }
    tempfile.path
  rescue Errno::ENOENT => e
    puts "Error writing to file: #{e.message}"
    e
  end
end
```

**Rspec example**:

```
it 'could not write to tempfile, so the report is created but without content' do
  allow(File).to receive(:open).and_return Errno::ENOENT
  response_code = post @url, params: { file_ids: [@file.id] }
  expect(response_code).to eql(200)
  assert_requested :get, /#{@s3_domain}.*/, body: @body, times: 1

  report = @file.frictionless_report
  expect(report.report).to eq(nil)
end
```

**Error**:

`tempfile` in the line

```
tempfile = Tempfile.new([upload_file_name, '.csv'])
```

receives `Errno::ENOENT`, indicating that the stub is going to `Tempfile` instead of to `File`.

How can I define the stub to go to `File` instead of to `Tempfile`?

Comment: `Tempfile.new` calls `File.open` [Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html#method-c-new) **Excerpt**: `@tmpfile = File.open(tmpname, @mode, **opts)` so you are interrupting this process by stubbing `File.open`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to reopen a [Tempfile](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.2/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html), it's already open and delegates to File.

```
def download_file
  tempfile = Tempfile.new([upload_file_name, '.csv'])
  tempfile.write(result.body.to_s)
  tempfile.path
# A method has an implicit begin.
rescue Errno::ENOENT => e
  puts "Error writing to file: #{e.message}"
  e
end
```

Then you can mock just `Tempfile.new`. Note that [exceptions are raised](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-10/docs/configuring-responses/raising-an-error), not returned.

```
it 'could not write to tempfile, so the report is created but without content' do
  # Exceptions are raised, not returned.
  allow(Tempfile).to receive(:new)
    .and_raise Errno::ENOENT

  response_code = post @url, params: { file_ids: [@file.id] }
  expect(response_code).to eql(200)
  assert_requested :get, /#{@s3_domain}.*/, body: @body, times: 1

  report = @file.frictionless_report
  expect(report.report).to eq(nil)
end
```

---

However, this remains fragile [glass-box testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-box_testing). Your test has knowledge of the implementation, if the implementation changes the test gives a false negative. And it still has to hope mocking Tempfile.new doesn't break something else.

Instead, [extract](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/extract-method.html) temp file creation from download_file.

```
private def new_temp_file_for_upload
  Tempfile.new([upload_file_name, '.csv'])
end

def download_file
  tempfile = new_temp_file_for_upload
  tempfile.write(result.body.to_s)
  tempfile.path
rescue Errno::ENOENT => e
  puts "Error writing to file: #{e.message}"
  e
end
```

Now the mocking can be targeted to a specific method in a specific object. And we can apply some [good rspec patterns](https://rspec.rubystyle.guide/).

```
context 'when the Tempfile cannot be created' do
  # Here I'm assuming download_file is part of the Controller being tested.
  before do
    allow(@controller).to receive(:new_temp_file_for_upload)
      .and_raise Errno::ENOENT
  end

  it 'creates the report without content' do
    post @url, params: { file_ids: [@file.id] }

    expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    assert_requested :get, /#{@s3_domain}.*/, body: @body, times: 1

    report = @file.frictionless_report
    expect(report.report).to be nil
  end
end
```

Note: returning "success" and an empty report after an internal failure is probably incorrect. It should return a 5xx error so the user knows there was a failure without having to look at the content.

download_file is doing too many things. It's both downloading a file and deciding what to do with a specific error. It should just download the file. Let something higher up in the call stack decide what to do with the exception. Methods which do one thing are simpler and more flexible and easier to test and less buggy.

```
private def new_temp_file_for_upload
  Tempfile.new([upload_file_name, '.csv'])
end

def download_file
  tempfile = new_temp_file_for_upload
  tempfile.write(result.body.to_s)
  tempfile.path
end
```

```
context 'when the download fails' do
  before do
    allow(@controller).to receive(:download_file)
      .and_raise "krunch!"
  end

  it 'responds with an error' do
    post @url, params: { file_ids: [@file.id] }

    expect(response).to have_http_status(:error)
  end
end
```

Note that no specific error is needed. It's enough that download_file raises an exception. This test now has no knowledge of the internals beyond knowing that download_file is called.

Comment: Very good answer, very informative and teaching about tests best practices. And solves the problem in such an elegant way. Let me only do a minor observation that after doing `tempfile.write(result.body.to_s)` it's necessary to do `tempfile.close` for the file to complete the writing process. And seems everything goes very well. Thank you!

Comment: @Caco Yes, `File.open` with a block takes care of that for you. Or you can use `tempfile.flush` to complete the writing process without closing.